Can any off-the-shelf .bst file omit author info?
A funding agency to which I'm submitting a proposal has requested that the References Cited section of the proposal "cite publications and presentations without the use of author names," stating that "such a citation should be as simple as providing a DOI reference number or listing the publication information without the inclusion of any authors."
I'm using \bibliographystyle{unsrt} with BibTeX.  (We have also been told that citations in the body of the proposal should not contain names, i.e., [1], [2], etc.)
I am unaware, though, of a simple way to omit contents of the \author{} field in my .bib files. Default unsrt output is currently:
[2] A. B. Charles. Fruity Pebbles Rule. J. Break. Cer., 10:4567 – 4589, September 2018.
The suggested listing would be:
[2] J. Break. Cer., 10:4567 – 4589, September 2018.
Technically, keeping the title and other non-author info (e.g., publisher) is permissible.
I could manually edit the citations generated by BibTeX, but would rather not...
I welcome any insights.

Rule of thumb: whenever you need something non-standard, biblatex is usually much easier to customise than bibtex

That said, this citation style is occasionally used, so I wouldn't be surprised if there is a BibTeX style for it somewhere.

Since this is a funding agency, not a journal, I'm assuming they don't care what you use to generate the bibliography. As mentioned in the comments, this sort of modification is much easier to do with biblatex. Here we can use its source mapping facility to remove the unneeded fields.  In this exmaple, I've suppressed the author field for all entries, and the titles for article entries only.  I'm using the biblatex-ext styles since they support other simple customizations (like removing the "In:" from articles, which is the somewhat odd biblatex default.)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=ext-numeric,articlein=false]{biblatex}
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=author, null]
    }
    \map{
    \pertype{article}
      \step[fieldset=title,null]
     }
  }
}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{companion,bertram,hyman}
\printbibliography
\end{document}


